# How to remove outer border from Silverlight AccentColor theme?

Tags: silverlight, themes

I'm playing with the Silverlight AccentColor theme.

Downloadable here:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e9da0eb8-f31b-4490-85b8-92c2f807df9e&displaylang=en

Demo page here:
http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/themes/accent.html

When I use the theme in a new project, there is a small grey border around the edge of the entire page.  It is not there on the demo site.

Can anyone tell me what is causing the border so I can remove it and have my app look like the demo site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why there is a grey border there... I also tried Chrome n FireFox they don't have the border as in IE9.

However, if you deploy the website project you will notice the grey border is gone. So probably you don't really need to worry about it. :)